# Display the size of the dot based on the value

Tags: qgis, style, value-list

I import a CSV File and for each coordinate, I get a point in the map.
Can I set a column for the value. Then the size should based on the value have a special size. Or based on all values, it should display from max to min value.

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS go to Layer Properties -> Style.

Either use 'Categorized' if you have a few values, 'Graduated' to be based on all the values (size is under the advanced menu) or create your own rules using 'Rule-based'.

See [HERE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113513/how-do-i-make-data-points-different-sizes-based-on-data) for duplicate question (comment from Joseph).

Comment: +1, some examples are also shown in a [similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113513/how-do-i-make-data-points-different-sizes-based-on-data).

Comment: Thanks for all ... did not see the other question as I wrote mine :-(