# Using BOTH size and colour to represent 2 pieces of information on single point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, color

[image: Points obeying two different rules, but how to integrate them into one circle]

I want the colour of the point to represent value from data column x (eg. rating from 1-5) and SIMULTANEOUSLY the size of the point to represent value from data column y (eg. Number of ratings 0-600).

I can swear that I have done this before but now I can't find how to do this in QGIS 2.10. It only gives the options to display using colour OR size.

Comment: You could use **Rule-based styling** in _Layer Properties > Style_ (I don't have QGIS 2.10 but I'm assuming this options still exists). I [posted](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113513/how-do-i-make-data-points-different-sizes-based-on-data/113528#113528) something similar where you set the sizes and colours of points. You can then add rules to filter the points.

Comment: @Joseph How do I add a screenshot to this thread? I have attempted to use your advise and I can see how to use the rule-based system. However, I am still unable to make each point incorporate both sets of instructions... Rather they are just listening to the size instruction and now ignoring the colour instruction (I apologize, this is harder to communicate without an image)

Comment: Interesting...you can add screenshots to your post by first clicking [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/162170/edit) and then you should see a toolbar with icons above your post. Click the icon to the right of the one which has this symbol `{ }`. You should also take a [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) as it provides tips and guidance.

Comment: I have added an image for clarity. Each point is obeying the two rules but how do i integrate both rules to dictating the size and shape of ONE circle per point? I am sure I am overlooking something and so I appreciate you help and patience.

Comment: I have also tried to use the 'add ranges to rule' option. So just having size rules, and then for each size rule line, using 'add ranges' based on second variable which uses colour... same effect as that shown in screenshot above.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit of a pain to set this up with QGIS 2.10+

You need to set the colour property as a range first and set the size of the symbol to be the smallest possible size for the size ranger.

Thereafter you can add the size rule in the rule dialogue. Thereafter you need to assign the colour to all sizes in every colour class. You can select all sizes but need to do this for every colour. Many sizes are no problem but you shouldn't use more than 10 colours.

[image]

Comment: This answer and the question helped me to understand that when I export the QGIS style as SLD to be used in the Geoserver, I can define the colors for classes in the QGIS and for the size in SLD use a predefined variable in the data,