# Red Amber Green colour system for point cluster map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, clustering, heat-map

I have a point cluster map of collisions occurred in an area, that shows all the cluster numbers in the same symbol/colour- however i want to create a map with the cluster colour updating according the cluster size i.e values above 20 would show in red; values between 10 - 20 in amber and below 10 in green.
[image]

Comment: Graduated Symbols with color ramp? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/339426/276

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QGIS 3.4.6 - symbology - Using Both size and colour to represent two pieces of information on single object](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339419/qgis-3-4-6-symbology-using-both-size-and-colour-to-represent-two-pieces-of-i)