# Drawing viewpoint-symbols in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-3

I made a viewpoint symbol in QGIS by styling a point to be be a circle and adding some lines that are rotated at different angles, and it ended up like so

[image: 360 viewpoint]

In a perfect world I would rather this symbol would be a polygon-style (rather than a point-style), so it would be the correct size at any zoom (without creating zoom-dependant symbols).

My problem is that I would like a half-circle, like this:

[image: half-viewpoint]

and a more-than-half-less-than-full circle like this:

[image: strange-viewpoint]

Any suggestions on how I can create a style like this in QGIS?

Comment: you can create a svg icon and add it,rotate etc!only is a suggestion

Comment: Look for answer about geometry generator that could give you some idea. this one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229961/creating-sector-lights-in-qgis for exemple could set you on the right track

Comment: how are segment count and the missing segments position defined?

Comment: The numer of segements are arbitrary. Just need to looke something like those examples. And I am not sure how I could define the missing sements. Maybe draw a circle and give it some value "be a circle of 270 degrees" or "be a full circle except 30 degrees, rotate 50 degrees"

Comment: Have you tried creating wedge buffers.[wedge buffers qgis docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#create-wedge-buffers-32)

Comment: Wedge buffers does look like it can be adapted for this.  Do you have attributes or fixed values for: Radius, Number of Segments, Wedge Width (arc angle), Starting Azimuth

Comment: The wedges were not a bad idea. I managed created a separate layers for the viewpoints, added some new datafields (azimuth, radius, etc) and ran the wedge buffer-algorithm. I got some wedges of the right sizes and rotations, but styling the generated buffer-layer to have lines that intersect at a central point was tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another SVG approach:

Save below texts as a SVG text file (let's say `petal.svg`) into your SVG folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="petal" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M150,150 v-100 a100,100 0 0,1 38.26834323,7.61205 z"
        fill="param(fill)" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 0.2"/>
</svg>
```

It will show a single petal (central angle ~ 22.5 degrees) when loaded onto QGIS as the SVG marker. Rotation angle starts at zero and increases clockwise. Please change fill and outline colors as needed.

[image]

For your usage, you might need to have two petals (45 degrees), three petals (67.5 degrees), and so on. <s>Please let me know if you need those variations</s>.

---

**EDIT** (added cases for two, three, and four petals)

Two petals:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="2 petals" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M150,150 v-100 A100,100 0 0,1 188.26834,57.61205 L150,150 L188.26834,57.61205 A100,100 0 0,1 220.7107,79.28932 z"
        fill="param(fill)" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 0.2"/>     
</svg>
```

Three petals:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="3 petals" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M150,150 v-100 A100,100 0 0,1 188.26834,57.61205 L150,150 L188.26834,57.61205 A100,100 0 0,1 220.7107,79.28932 L150,150 L220.7107,79.28932 A100,100 0 0,1 242.388,111.7317 z"
        fill="param(fill)" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 0.2"/>     
</svg>
```

Four petals:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="4 petals" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M150,150 v-100 A100,100 0 0,1 188.26834,57.61205 L150,150 L188.26834,57.61205 A100,100 0 0,1 220.7107,79.28932 L150,150 L220.7107,79.28932 A100,100 0 0,1 242.388,111.7317 L150,150 L242.388,111.7317  A100,100 0 0,1 250,150 z"
        fill="param(fill)" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 0.2"/>     
</svg>
```

---

Or, adding layers of SVG markers may be an option...but this is largely manual work and not recommendable.

[image]

---

**Another option** -- **Shape Tools Plugin**

If you do not have to have "spokes", I would recommend [Shape Tools](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-shapetools-plugin) plugin. Unlike `Wedge buffers` in QGIS3, you can set `start` and `end` azimuth directly from your attribute fields. It makes the things much easier and quicker.

[image]

Comment: Just Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. Try this steps:

1. Open your PNG with inkscape and save it as SVG (plane) within a folder (may be defould SVG symbols within QGIS is a good place).
2. Within QGIS, go to System --> Options --> System. Then add your folder path to the SVG paths. Close QGIS and re-open it just to be sure that this new folder path is going to be loaded.
3. Go to layer properties and look for your new symbols. I just tried yours and it worked.

[image]

Comment: In case you need to change symbol size automatically, work around with this options: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113513/making-data-points-different-sizes-based-on-data-using-qgis